# How to change many settings in scope at once in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to group settings by the context in which they apply in my build.sbt. Instead of

```
foo in ThisBuild := bar

baz in ThisBuild := bar

bar in Compile := 5

quux in Compile := 7
```

I'd like something that roughly looks like (don't care much about the specific syntax/API, just the conceptual grouping and lack of repetition)

```
in(ThisBuild) {
  foo := bar
  baz := bar
}

in(Compile) {
  bar  := 5
  quux := 7
}
```

Is such a thing possible/clean/idiomatic?

Comment: I think you could define it using [inScope](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Project.scala.html#sbt;ProjectExtra.inScope(4301c25b74)) method, but I'm not sure if it's the most idiomatic way.

Answer (score 3):

For `Compile` configuration use `inConfig` as follows:

```
inConfig(Compile) {
  Seq(
    bar  := 5,
    quux := 7
  )
}
```

For `ThisBuild` scope use `inScope` as follows:

```
inScope(ThisScope.copy(project=Select(ThisBuild))) {
  Seq(
    foo := bar,
    baz := bar
  )
}
```

Note that all the `in*` methods work for `Seq`s.

Note also that since they appear in `build.sbt` file they're automatically scoped to the project the build definition belongs to. Obviously, `in ThisBuild` settings belong to the build.

As to the idiomatic nature of using the `in*` methods in `*.sbt` files, I have never seen them in the files. Since they're pretty new (since sbt 0.13) people could be yet to catch up with their use.

The trait `ProjectExtra` offers `inConfig`, `inTask` and `inScope` methods. [As @copumpkin pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853705/changing-multiple-sbt-settings-in-a-given-scope-in-build-sbt/24874258#comment38678126_24874258) there's no `inProject` method that would complement the others.  I've no idea why, but with `inScope` it is **not** necessary and neither are the `inConfig` and `inTask` since they pretty much map a scope to a config or a task with the other axes unchanged.

For reference, this is the definition of `Scope`:

```
final case class Scope(project: ScopeAxis[Reference], config: ScopeAxis[ConfigKey], task: ScopeAxis[AttributeKey[_]], extra: ScopeAxis[AttributeMap])
```

Comment: How about changing a group of settings in a given project? or in other axes? I've found `inScope` and `inConfig`, but there's no `inProject` or `inTask`.

Comment: Whoops, there is an `inTask`, but still no `inProject`.

Comment: See my updated answer. Keep asking until we find a better solution/answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Defaults.scala

As a supplement to [Jacek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24874258/3827), I'd encourage you to see sbt 0.13.5's [JvmPlugin.scala](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/plugins/JvmPlugin.scala.html) and [Defaults.scala](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html). `JvmPlugin` is an auto plugin that's enabled by default and adds basic JVM tasks like `compile:compile` and `test:test`.

#### Defaults.defaultConfigs

For instance, [`Defaults.defaultConfigs`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Defaults.defaultConfigs) adds both `compile:compile` and `test:test` as follows:

```
lazy val defaultConfigs: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  inConfig(Compile)(compileSettings) ++
  inConfig(Test)(testSettings) ++
  inConfig(Runtime)(Classpaths.configSettings)
```

#### Defaults.testSettings

As Jacek noted, the expected type on the passed in settings are all `Seq[Def.Setting[_]]`. Like

```
lazy val testSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = configSettings ++ testTasks
```

#### Defaults.testTasks

These sequences can be constructed by appending reused sequences that are scoped in different ways as [testTasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Defaults.testTasks):

```
lazy val testTasks: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  testTaskOptions(test) ++
  testTaskOptions(testOnly) ++
  testTaskOptions(testQuick) ++
  testDefaults ++ Seq(
    ....
    test := {
        val trl = (testResultLogger in (Test, test)).value
        val taskName = Project.showContextKey(state.value)(resolvedScoped.value)
        trl.run(streams.value.log, executeTests.value, taskName)
    },
    testOnly <<= inputTests(testOnly),
    testQuick <<= inputTests(testQuick)
)
```

### Project scoping and auto plugin

If you're using multi-project build.sbt, the project scoping would be done by passing the settings to project's settings method.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))

lazy val foo = project.
  settings(yourSettings: _*).
  settings(someOtherSettings: _*)

lazy val bar = project.
  settings(yourSettings: _*).
  settings(someOtherSettings: _*)
```

You can define `def yourSettings` in `build.sbt` (or `project/foo.scala`). When you start to find passing settings explicitly to be tedious, you can define an autoplugin similar to sbt's `JvmPlugin`. This would let you write:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))

lazy val foo = project.
  enablePlugins(FooPlugin, BarPlugin)

lazy val bar = project.
  enablePlugins(FooPlugin, BarPlugin)
```

**Edit**:

If you make `FooPlugin` and `BarPlugin` triggered out of thin air, you could write:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))

lazy val foo, bar = project
```

See [Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html) for the details.

I want to clarify that you can chose the degree of magic/automation when it comes to auto plugins. In the above, both `FooPlugin` and `BarPlugin` are triggered out of nothing, but you could easily make `BarPlugin` triggered by `FooPlugin` or not triggered at all. This is meant to automate things like "use coffeescript plugin for all web-related projects". I hope I'm still on-topic with your question "I want to group settings by the context."

Comment: This all seems very magical :( are plugins going to become a standard part of a multi-project build that wants to factor out common settings in cross-cutting ways?

Comment: When I talk to people using sbt at work in conferences, it seems like plugins are already a part of any build to standardize on common settings for different types of projects. Auto plugins just track dependencies between each other better than the old plugins.

Comment: Plugins are `Seq[Setting[_]]` already. AutoPlugins make their application to projects easier without having them added with `settings` explicitly. That's why they're called **auto** plugins after all.